# Flex: Ignore whitespace one by one or in bulk?

Tags: performance, flex-lexer

With Flex, does it matter for performance whether whitespace is ignored as

```
[ \t]  { }
```

or as

```
[ \t]+ { }
```

?

Note that the actions are empty in both cases.

Comment: As far as I know, matching longer strings is better because the lexer doesn't need to stop after each character and reset its state machine. This may not hold true if you have a lot of whitespaces in a row (more then can fit into the Flex buffer).

Comment: There are also character classes `[:blank:]` and `[:space:]` you may consider using. https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html